# Reference for a theorem about necessary and sufficient conditions for configuration of n-tuples of points.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, irreducible-polynomials, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, plane-curves

I'm writing my thesis and at a certain point I claim, and indeed it turns out to be true from discussions with my supervisors, that certain configurations for n-tuples of points, in a curve of degree k, have the following property:

**If there is an n-tuple of points of $\mathbb{P}^2$ such that the configuration C is possible than the configuration C is possible for any n-tuple**

For example it's possible that given 8 points on an irreducible quartic one of them is a triple point and the other 7 are non-singular points, but then I claim that given any 8-uple in $\mathbb{P}^2$ there is a quartic with a triple point in one of them and passing through the other 7.

I claim that these configurations are all possible configuration on curves of degree bigger than 3 if we consider an 8-uple.

What I need is a reference for such theorem that I'm quite sure exists

Comment: What is an "n-uple"?

Comment: A vector of lenght n made of points.of the space

For example an 4-uple of $\mathbb{Z}$ is something like (3, 4, -2, 5)

Comment: This thing has the name **t**uple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a complete answer.
However it turns out that the best way to exclude a configuaration is to use Bezout theorem.

For example a cubic can have at most one singularity, if it had two and we considered a line through the two we woud get an intersection mutliplicity of 2+2=4 that is bigger than the 3*1=3 coming from Bezout.

In some case we need to use singular curves, for example a singular cubic with the signularity (a double point) on the triple point of a quintic has intersection multiplicity 3*2=6 on the point alone